# Sens du mot 'mixité'

Tags: usage, académique

Dans un sondage d'une université j'ai lu la question :

> Quels objectifs ou actions se donner pour développer la mixité ?

J'ai du mal de comprendre ce qui distingue, dans ce contexte, le mot mixité des mots comme égalité, parité, équité, pluralité/diversité de genre, etc.

Mixité implique seulement l'homme et la femme ou tous les genres ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixité est dérivé de mixte qui signifie mélangé mais est principalement utilisé pour désigner le mélange de personnes des deux sexes, en particulier dans un contexte scolaire ou universitaire.

L'école mixte, c'est donc l'école qui accueille à la fois des filles et des garçons.

Dans un contexte universitaire, développer la mixité peut vouloir dire promouvoir l'arrivée d'éléments du sexe opposé dans les filières traditionnellement soit masculines, soit féminines.

Rien n'interdit cependant de parler par extension de mixité sociale, culturelle, linguistique, etc. mais c'est en général mentionné explicitement.

Les autres mots proposés sont tous plus ou moins proches, mais avec des nuances :

- égalité : traitements et droits identiques, pas de privilèges ;
- parité : nombre identique de membres de chaque groupe ;
- équité : traitements justes, équitables, partage, justice ;
- pluralité : ne pas avoir un seul groupe, laisser une place aux "autres" ;
- diversité : inclusion de personnes d'origines, de cultures, de situations différentes de celles de la majorité.

Comment: Merci ! C'est super, ta réponse. Alors, mixité inclut les deux genres (male et female) seulement ?

Comment: Inclut les personnes des deux sexes, masculin et féminin.

Comment: Genre peut être utilisé pour désigner sexe, non ?

Comment: Ça dépend. Ce n'est pas tout à fait la même chose. On dit *l'école accueille des élèves des deux sexes*, mais je n'ai jamais entendu un francophone dire *l'école accueille des élèves des deux genres.* La formule pourrait être *l'école accueille des élèves sans distinction de genre*.

Comment: @Dimitris, l'utilisation de genre pour le sexe est un de ses mots qui nous reviens de l'anglais et qui se mets à faire des dérives, parfois étranges comme "genré", même s'il existe déjà des termes appropriés en français. Genre à un sens plus large que sexe, il désigne un ou des groupes d'individus qui partagent une même caractéristique. Pour approfondir: http://www.culture.fr/Ressources/FranceTerme/Recommandations-d-usage/GENDER